# Auto formatting a 100mb+ C++ file

Tags: c++, pretty-print, autoformatting

I have a 100mb auto generated C++ file with broken formatting that I want to autoformat (indentation primarily).

All editors I have tried either crash or do not allow autoformatting more than a few megabytes of text.

By auto formatting I mean indentation.

Beyond writing some custom code to do this how can I auto format 100mb C/c++ files?

I have tried:
VSCode
Visual Studio
Notepad++

Why do I need this?

We need to search the code for meta data (it is decompiled from assembly) and it makes it a lot easier to read if its indented properly.

We don't know ahead of time which parts of the code we need.. until we need it. It needs to be a single file to make it simpler to search for names/functions without constantly searching 1000s of individual files (if we did it per function).

The original C code would be millions of lines long which is why its so large

Comment: `clang-format`?

Comment: Have you tried to generate multiple smaller source files instead?

Comment: The method we are using it is not easily achievable making small files.

Comment: Generally, generated code is not made for humans to work with, so you should not be formatting it. That said, if the code contains multiple functions, then separate it into files at the function boundaries and format those files separately. If it does not contain multiple functions, then humans **really** should not be working with 100 MB of code; their brains are not up to the task, even with formatting. (I presume you meant “100 MB” for megabytes, not “100mb”; 100 millibits is a tiny amount of code.)

Comment: We need to search the code for meta data (it is decompiled from assembly) and it makes it a lot easier to read if its indented properly. We don't know ahead of time which parts of the code we need.. until we need it. It needs to be a single file to make it simpler to search for names/functions without constantly searching 1000s of individual files (if we did it per function). The original C code would be millions of lines long which is why its so large.

Comment: What's the name of the program you use to produce C and C++ code from assembly?

Comment: @rollsch *All editors I have tried either crash or do not allow autoformatting more than a few megabytes of text.* -- You can try the UltraEdit text editor.  It isn't free, however.

Comment: @TedLyngmo We are using Ghidra

Comment: @rollsch Ok, did you see [this](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/1343)? It seems they have formatter settings for eclipse.

Comment: Im just trying clang-format from the cmdline. Its using 38gb of RAM but it seems to be working. I will report back. Thanks for the suggestions people.

Comment: Ok clang-format did exactly what we needed. Thanks @TedLyngmo if the question is reopened and you answer I will mark that as the solution. Cheers everyone.

Comment: Formatting generated code is an exercise in futility. If you want it look cleaner, generate it cleaner.

Comment: @sweenish I am asking to fix simple indentation only, it is not rocket science as proven by clang-format

Comment: And I'm saying it's pointless to format generated code. Not sure what there is to misunderstand. Generate it to be cleaner instead of running a tool over it again.

Comment: We don't generate the code, a tool that we do not control generates the code. Formatting the tool with clang-format made the file far more readable. Are you always this unhelpful and argumentative?

Answer (score 3):

My first three recommendations are text editors, but I don't know if they'll work for you: 1) JEdit has a CLangBeauty plugin for reformatting source. 2) I assume Netbeans has a similar plugin, and can handle large files.  3) Then, there is QtCreator, which is available in a Windows version.  If you let it install Qt, it will be a large install, but I think you can do a custom install and just get the IDE; but it is very good at large files and can reformat them.  Just choose the Open Source Edition at the download.

Here's a page with a list of text editors than can open files *gigabytes* in size: "[How to open Gigabyte-sized text files on Windows](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/22/how-to-open-gigabyte-sized-text-files-on-windows/)".  I've used glogg to view huge text files successfully; although it's features are minimalistic.

In order to reformat "C" and "C++" code, there is a handy utility "[UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/)" that can call a number of code beautifiers/formatters.  It was lasted updated in 2012, though.  One of the command-line tools it can call is "[Uncrustify](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify)".

Uncrustify is a command-line utility for reformatting code, and should be more memory efficient than the editor-based methods, as will be command-line code formatters in general. It is probably the most powerful at customizing the format it puts things in than the others.  It has recently been updated as of this writing. `clang-format` will probably also do it too.  These are command line utilities, so it's best to run them from a command prompt, call them in a pipe, or from an external GUI like UniversalIndentGUI; at least on Windows.  Uncrustify has a LOT of configuration options you can make.  I was also able to contact the author, and get him to add a feature for code formatting that I felt to be important.  Uncrustify should do it if none of the others will do.